# IOTA lightwallet, transaction confirmed, address not attached to tangle, balance 0

Tags: transaction, wallet

I have two seeds set up and wanted to transfer 99.5 Miotas from one to the other. After creating the transaction, it was pending for about 3 hours and i published it to the network 3 more times. Now one is confirmed, the other 2 are *"Persistenz: A reattachment confirmed"*. No Miota arrived in my other wallet. I did not attach the address to the tangle.

```
 21/12/2017 20:25
SAZCSWSCRYJBQTPRPNJUGZOKQZ9PHNNECFMPMODILWMKXFILLDFMDMTJHVZYLVPEGHVGKVXZFGEBSFMHCMZNMQFGQX
Bundle Confirmed
-99.5 Mi
21/12/2017 17:42
SAZCSWSCRYJBQTPRPNJUGZOKQZ9PHNNECFMPMODILWMKXFILLDFMDMTJHVZYLVPEGHVGKVXZFGEBSFMHCMZNMQFGQX
Bundle not confirmed
-99.5 Mi
21/12/2017 16:30
SAZCSWSCRYJBQTPRPNJUGZOKQZ9PHNNECFMPMODILWMKXFILLDFMDMTJHVZYLVPEGHVGKVXZFGEBSFMHCMZNMQFGQX
Bundle not confirmed
-99.5 Mi
```

Any idea whats happening there? Could it be possible that the receiving wallet does not see the transaction, because it is not attached to the tangle? I already tried to generate about 40 addresses in the receiving wallet, in the hope that the one which showed up, shows up again…

Comment: How much miota was debited from your sending wallet?

Also, it's advisable to first attach an address before using it for any transaction.